How can I profile CUDA code for memory management?
I recently got started on CUDA. I wrote CUDA code to primarily manage memory on my GPU and the associated shared memory. Is there a way to profile the code and how much memory gets allocated/freed?
As of now, I query the GPU after each memory command and print it out...

Just a quick point — the CUDA GPU side language has been a C++ dialect for about 10 years, rather than C. Some C programmer are a bit unhappy about calling CUDA C, that’s why I have edited your question

For global memory you can trace usage over time with Nsight Systems using --cuda-memory-usage. Tracking shared memory between "memory commands"  makes no sense so I'm not sure what you mean.

Note the amount of shared memory allocated for a kernel is constant during its execution (pre-allocated) -- not dynamic. You can also see that in Nsight: in the occupancy calculator. Regarding the heap-memory dynamically allocated in CUDA kernels, it is also preallocated and bounded (AFAIK something like 16 MiB is preallocated per kernel by default).

Some example code would make it easier to understand what kind of memory operations you want to profile.
